# How do I add keyframes to an object that I want to sculpt at time intervals?

Tags: animation, sculpting, keyframes, timeline

Is it possible to have blender follow key frames based on sculpting differences of an object?  I have a glacier in Blender that I am trying to sculpt at time intervals on my timeline, but blender does not register that the sculpt of the glacier is different at time=0 vs time=10.

Answer (score 0):

Key Mesh add-on can be used for this, but it is WIP.

More info about the add-on:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPvLQH17Y2Q&ab_channel=askNK

Comment: Can you please point me towards other resources that can be helpful to me?  Ideally I could virtually talk with someone who can help me create my desired animation.  Do you have any recommendations for how I can get help?

Answer (score 0):

Could you not figure out a way to use shape keys? They work on the mesh deformation from scultping.

[image]